# named ranges in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of items in excel and I would like to name the range "Account Payments". It works for ranges with one word names but not with 2 or more words. how do I do this?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only use a single string to name a range -

`AccountPayments` or `Account_Payments` will work.

> The following is a list of syntax rules that you need to be aware of
>   when you create and edit names.
>
> **Valid characters**    The first character of a name must be a letter, an
>   underscore character (_), or a backslash (). Remaining characters in
>   the name can be letters, numbers, periods, and underscore characters.
>
> NOTE   You cannot use the uppercase and lowercase characters "C", "c",
>   "R", or "r" as a defined name, because they are all used as a
>   shorthand for selecting a row or column for the currently selected
>   cell when you enter them in a Name or Go To text box.
>
> **Cell references disallowed**    Names cannot be the same as a cell
>   reference, such as Z$100 or R1C1.
>
> **Spaces are not valid**    Spaces are not allowed as part of a name. Use
>   the underscore character (_) and period (.) as word separators, such
>   as, Sales_Tax or First.Quarter.
>
> **Name length**    A name can contain up to 255 characters.
>
> **Case sensitivity**    Names can contain uppercase and lowercase letters.
>   Excel does not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase characters
>   in names. For example, if you created the name Sales and then create
>   another name called SALES in the same workbook, Excel prompts you to
>   choose a unique name.

[source](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmlearn_more_about_using_names)